# Altering proc attempting to start distributed transaction

Tags: sql-server

Example Code:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL Serializable
go
begin transaction
go
alter procedure abc 
as
begin
select top 10 * from database2.dbname.dbo.dbtable
end
commit transaction
```

I received the error:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "database2" returned
>   message "The transaction manager has disabled its support for
>   remote/network transactions.".
>
> Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure abc, Line 4 [Batch Start Line
>   4] The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider
>   "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "database2" was unable to begin a
>   distributed transaction.

I'm running on an Azure managed instance, but I suspect this will happen any time MSDTC is disabled.

This is occurring as part of a larger deployment script and wrapping the deployment in a transaction is desired.  Is there a way to prevent this error?  Or do I have to live without wrapping it all in a transaction?

Note that leaving the isolation level at READ COMMITTED does not cause the issue, but my deployment engine (SQL Compare) doesn't let me disable that part.

Comment: Looks like the isolation level can be configured. https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/20805/setting-the-transaction-isolation-level

Comment: Unfortunately, that appears to be part of an SQL Compare SDK and not the main product.  I haven't found anything in the product for that.  But, you did remind me that I'm an idiot for not asking them.  I was looking for an SQL solution, but going to the source would be smart.

Comment: You might try turning off the distributed transaction option for the linked server: `EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'database2', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'false';`.